# OpenVPN does not connect VIA FrootVPN

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, openvpn, network-adapter

Suddenly quit working... again...

OpenVPN 2.3.6 (32 bit) 
Latest FrootVPN config file
Windows 7 64 bit
Port 1194 is open for UDP AND TCP

I have been told to use 32 bit OpenVPN due to bugs, and it helped with my last issue. The network adapter "Local Area Connection 3" is not being used...

[image]
[image: network adapters/map]

Config (removed cert and key):

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
ns-cert-type server
verb 3
<ca>
</key>
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1194
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1195
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1196
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1197
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1198
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1199
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1200
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1201
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1202
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1203
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1204
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1205
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1206
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1207
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1208
remote se-openvpn.frootvpn.com 1209
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Uninstall OpnVPN
Delete OpenVPN from your programs directory
Do A registry clean
Uninstall the TAP-Windows adapter
Reboot
Install OpenVPN

And there we have it!

Question asked over a year ago and nobody else chimed in. I am marking this as solved now.